# Is it possible to get all active users details who are logginned into the website

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to get all active users details who are logginned into the website using asp.net. I am able to get active users count, but I need active users details (like username).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using membership, take a look at this: [Get+All+logged+in+users](http://forums.asp.net/t/1707751.aspx?Get%20All%20logged%20in%20users)